# Find the percentage of total percentage?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table consist of Net Payment, Bank, Bank Percentage of each employee. Here I  have to calculate the overall sum of Net Payment with associate bank percentage.

```
EmpCode    Bank Bank% NetPayment 
 001        PDB  70%    50,000    
 001        EDB  30%    50,000    
 002        PDB  80%    30,000    
 003        PDB  100%   25,000
```

Here for PDB bank EMP 001 and 002 Main net Payment is 50,000,30,000 and 70%,80% of 001,002 Net pay  will go to PDB Bank and 30% will go to EDB Bank for 001 and for rest of employees in the list will go to PDB Bank.

I want to sum up the  total amount for each Bank and result would be

```
Bank TotalNetPayable
PDB    84,000
EDB    15,000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select bank, sum(bank% * netpayment) as TotalNetPayable
from t
group by bank;
```

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would build the query like this:

```
   SELECT Bank, SUM(NetPayment * (Bank%)/100) 
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Bank
```

Remember to divide by 100 the percentage.

I think that should work.